# How do I remove double quote "" from JSON Value

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx, double-quotes

I am doing my Javascript. And just imported JSON and printed it out with JSON.stringfy
I am using that site because the JSON contains the URL which I want to link.
I am not getting what I really need as the output.

```
description": "www.site.com"
```

This is what I get in my console:

```
"www.site.com"
```

This is what I actually want, and remove the quotes.

```
www.site.com
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you please provide a test case?

Comment: Please share your source code that is importing/parsing/printing the json

Comment: Provide your code with json parsing

Comment: We need to see your code to help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure what your requirement is but you can do this.
Try Replace function;

```
const obj = {description: "www.site.com"};
JSON.stringify(obj.description).replace(/"/g,"");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var someStr = 'He said "Hello, my name is Foo"';
console.log(someStr.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
```

That should do the trick... (if your goal is to replace all double quotes).